# OpenCV - Floodfill onto new Mat

Tags: image-processing, opencv, flood-fill

Given a point on an image, I'd like to floodfill all points connected to that point - but onto a new image.  A naive way to do this would be to floodfill the original image to a special magic colour value.  Then, visit each pixel, and copy all pixels with this magic colour value to the new image.  There must be a better way!

Comment: What's wrong with copying original image to another one and work on that image??

Comment: I would need some way of setting everything else in that image to black.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Why don't you use the second variant of [cv::floodFill](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#floodfill) to create a mask?

> int floodFill(InputOutputArray image, InputOutputArray mask, Point
>   seedPoint, Scalar newVal, Rect* rect=0, Scalar loDiff=Scalar(), Scalar
>   upDiff=Scalar(), int flags=4 )

- Original image

```cpp
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("squares.png");
```

[image: squares]

- First variant

```cpp
cv::floodFill(img, cv::Point(150,150), cv::Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0));
```

[image: img]

This is the `img`

- Second variant

```cpp
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows + 2, img.cols + 2, CV_8U);
cv::floodFill(img, mask, cv::Point(150,150), 255, 0, cv::Scalar(), cv::Scalar(),
  4 + (255 << 8) + cv::FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY);
```

[image: mask]

This is the `mask`. `img` doesn't change

If you go with this though, note that:

> **Since the mask is larger than the filled image, a pixel (x,y) in image corresponds to the pixel (x+1, y+1) in the mask.**