# How to draw transparent polygon?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to draw a transparent polygon (triangle in this case). But I'm unable to find any examples by searching the web.

```
// Create image
Mat image = Mat::zeros( 400, 400, CV_8UC3 );

// Draw a circle 
/** Create some points */
Point Treangle_points[1][20];
Treangle_points[0][0] = Point( 150, 100 );
Treangle_points[0][1] = Point( 275, 350 );
Treangle_points[0][2] = Point( 50, 20 );

const Point* ppt[1] = { Treangle_points[0] };
int npt[] = { 3 };

fillPoly( image, ppt, npt, 1, Scalar( 255, 255, 255 ), 8 );
imshow("Image",image);
```

Comment: Maybe this will help... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12575882/2836621

Answer (score 3):

To use transparency, you need to work with `alpha` channel, in BGRA color space. `alpha = 0` means fully transparent, while `alpha = 255` means opaque colors.

You need to create a `CV_8UC4` image (aka `Mat4b`), or convert a 3 channel image to 4 channel with `cvtColor(src, dst, COLOR_BGR2BGRA)`, and draw a transparent filled shape, with alpha channel equals to 0.

If you load a 4 channel image, remember to use `imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);`

Transparent triangle (the transparency is rendered as white here, you can see that the image is in fact transparent opening it with your preferred image viewer):

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Create a BGRA green image 
    Mat4b image(300, 300, Vec4b(0,255,0,255));

    vector<Point> vertices{Point(100, 100), Point(200, 200), Point(200, 100)};

    vector<vector<Point>> pts{vertices};
    fillPoly(image, pts, Scalar(0,0,0,0));
    //                                ^ this is the alpha channel                              

    imwrite("alpha.png", image);
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**

`imshow` won't show transparency correctly, since it just ignores the `alpha` channel.

---

C++98 version

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Create a BGRA green image 
    Mat4b image(300, 300, Vec4b(0, 255, 0, 255));

    Point vertices[3];
    vertices[0] = Point(100, 100);
    vertices[1] = Point(200, 200);
    vertices[2] = Point(200, 100);

    const Point* ppt[1] = { &vertices[0] };
    int npt[] = { 3 };

    fillPoly(image, ppt, npt, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), 8);

    imwrite("alpha.png", image);

    imshow("a", image);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question has been really an old one. And I find some answers but they are not what I want. I want set a polygon roi transparent which overlaps that areas without help of alpha channel, ie. we can still observe the background through that transparent area without a 4 channels image:
[image: a quadrangle transparent area]

Here is the code:

```cpp
// img: input 3 channels image
// roi : polygon represents by points
// color: transparent base color
// alpha: transparent ratio
// out:   out image with transparent area
void SetTransparentColor(cv::Mat &img, vector<vector<cv::Point> > &roi, cv::Scalar color, double alpha, cv::Mat &out)
{
  cv::Mat layer = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);

  cv::fillPoly(layer, roi, color);

  cv::addWeighted(img, alpha, layer, 1-alpha, 0, out);
}
```

I have also tried some other ways, and the core idea is the same, by merging two area pixels with alpha value which stands for transparent ratio. But they are time consuming. So I will not put these codes here.

Answer (score 0):

as an addition to Miki's answer the sample code below maybe useful.

for more information see http://answers.opencv.org/question/73114

see also [sample code of OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gabbc7ef1aa2edfaa87772f1202d67e0ce&gsc.tab=0)

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main( int, char** argv )
{
    Mat image(400, 400, CV_8UC4, Scalar(0, 0, 200,0));
    Mat bgra[4];
    split(image,bgra);

    rectangle(bgra[3],Rect(100,100,200,200),Scalar(255),-1);

    merge(bgra,4,image);
    imwrite("transparent1.png",image);

    rectangle(bgra[3],Rect(150,150,100,100),Scalar(127),-1);
    merge(bgra,4,image);
    imwrite("transparent2.png",image);

    bgra[3] = bgra[3] * 0.5; // here you can change transparency %50
    // bgra[3] = bgra[3] + 50 // you can add some value
    // bgra[3] = bgra[3] - 50 // you can subtract some value

    merge(bgra,4,image);
    imwrite("transparent3.png",image);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```