# OpenCV transparent background

Tags: java, opencv

I have OpenCV mask and I need to extract the region from the original image by this mask into the new Mat object.

This is my current code:

```
Mat tmp = input.clone(); //original image
Core.bitwise_not(mask, mask); // invert mask
tmp.setTo(new Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), mask);
```

right now the following line `tmp.setTo(new Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), mask)` produces the following output:

[image]

where we have the black background.

Instead of black, I need the transparent background. Please show how it can be implemented with OpenCV.

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33792872/5008845)

Comment: @Miki I'm using Java and unable to convert this example. For example, there is no Mat4b class in OpenCV Java wrapper.